# Check Collision between Label and Rectangle?

Tags: c#, label, collision

i have a question: If a label is moving with a timer from left to right and after a while is meeting a rectangle. How can i get the collision between them?

Here is the rectangle:

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightCyan, new Rectangle(Pipe1[0], 0, PipeWidth, Pipe1[1]));
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightCyan, new Rectangle(Pipe1[2], Pipe1[3], PipeWidth, this.Height - Pipe1[3]));
```

Some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Label myLabel = new Label();

myLabel.Text = "BOB";
Rectangle rec = myLabel.Bounds;
Rectangle rec2 = new Rectangle(30, 10, 20, 40);
Rectangle intersect = Rectangle.Intersect(rec, rec2);
if (intersect != Rectangle.Empty)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Intersection!");
}
```

You'd substitute for "rec2" the rectangle you built above. Obviously, you'd want to build it and assign it to a Rectangle reference and then refer to it in both places by that variable.

Answer (score 3):

Store the 2 rectangles in local variables, then use `Rectangle.IntersectsWith()` to check if they overlap.

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: To get the Label's Rectangle, use the `Bounds` property.